# Integral of $\big((1+\cos(x))\sin(x)\big)^2$

Tags: trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

What is 
$$\int \big((1+\cos(x))\sin(x)\big)^2dx$$
?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried to open the expression like sin^2 + 2cos sin ^2 + cos ^2 sin^2 but could not go further

Comment: @Vinod upper comment, thanks

Comment: For the second term after multiplying out, use $u$-substitution.  For the first term use either power reducing or parts.  For the last term, use power reducing or a trig identity.

Comment: Hint:

$sin^{2}(x) = 1/2(1 - cos2x),cos^{2}(x) = 1/2(1 + cos2x)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use $$\begin{align}(1 + \cos t)^2\sin^2 t &= \sin^2 t + 2\sin^2 t \cos t + \sin^2 t \cos^2 t\\
&=\frac 12 - \frac 12 \cos 2t + 2\sin^2 t \cos t + \frac 18 - \frac 18 \cos 4t \\
&=\frac 58 - \frac 12 \cos 2t +  2\sin^2 t \cos t - \frac 18 \cos 4t \end{align}$$

now we can integrate $$\int (1 + \cos t)^2\sin^2 t\, dt =  \frac 58 t - \frac 14 \sin 2t + \frac 23 \sin^3 t  - \frac 1{32} \sin 4t + C $$

Comment: There's a small error in the second line: it should end in $\dfrac 18 -\dfrac18\cos4t$, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Bernard, thanks for spotting the error. i have fixed it.

Comment: Didn't you forget a $2$ in the rhs of the first line ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks. is everybody happy now.

Comment: @abel. As I use to say, if I was given a cent for each of my typo's, I should be a billionaire ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, i tend to make this kind of mistakes even in my teaching. my student are all too familiar with them. i have been teaching them to double check their answers.

Answer (score 3):

Use $\cos x=(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})/2$, $\sin x=-i(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})/2$

You get
$$
-\frac{1}{16}\int\bigl((2+e^{ix}+e^{-ix})(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})\bigr)^2\,dx
$$
Let's simplify the internal product:
$$
(2+e^{ix}+e^{-ix})(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})=
2e^{ix}-2e^{-ix}+e^{2ix}-1+1-e^{-2ix}
$$
and squaring it gives
$$
4e^{2ix}+4e^{-2ix}+e^{4ix}+e^{-4ix}-8+4e^{3ix}-4e^{-ix}
-4e^{ix}+4e^{-3ix}-2
$$
that we can reorder as
$$
e^{4ix}+e^{-4ix}+4e^{3ix}+4e^{-3ix}+4e^{2ix}+4e^{-2ix}-4e^{ix}-4e^{-ix}-10
$$
or, switching back to the cosine,
$$
2\cos4x+8\cos3x+8\cos2x-8\cos x-10
$$
so the integral is
$$
-\frac{1}{16}\int(
  2\cos4x+8\cos3x+8\cos2x-8\cos x-10
)\,dx
$$
and we get
$$
-\frac{1}{32}\sin 4x-\frac{1}{6}\sin3x-\frac{1}{4}\sin2x+\frac{1}{2}\sin x+\frac{5}{8}x+C
$$